# Build Qt/cmake based project in GitHub Actions

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, github-actions, msys2

I'm using Qt 5.12.11 in my project. As I wanted to use the software both on linux and win, I selected gcc compiler (I use MSYS2, so gcc is 10.3.0). The local build is ok both for linux and win, but the build via GitHub Actions fails on finding the qt (no matter if I set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or Qt5_DIR or not).

So this is where I'm stuck for a while. Has anyone encountered such problems or have any ideas on it?

github action looks like

```
name: Build

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

env:
  BUILD_TYPE: Release

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    defaults:
        run:
            shell: msys2 {0}

    steps:
      - uses: msys2/setup-msys2@v2
        with:
            install: mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
            msystem: mingw64
            release: false

      - name: Install Qt
        uses: jurplel/install-qt-action@v2
        with:
          version: '5.12.11'
          host: 'windows'
          target: 'desktop'
          arch: 'win64_mingw73'
          dir: '${{github.workspace}}/qt/'
          install-deps: 'true'

      - name: List files in Qt
        run: find ${{env.Qt5_Dir}}

      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Configure CMake
        run: cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${{env.BUILD_TYPE}} -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="${{env.Qt5_Dir}}/lib/cmake/" -DQt5_DIR=${{env.Qt5_Dir}}/lib/cmake/Qt5/ -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" -B '${{github.workspace}}'/build

      - name: Build
        run: cmake --build '${{github.workspace}}'/build --target RePr
```

I've also tried `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="${{env.Qt5_Dir}}/lib/cmake/Qt5/"` but it didn't help. :( if I set the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH directly from the cmakelists I observe the same behavior.

CMakeLists on which it fails is quite simple and usual (it's a nested package that uses qt, so don't be confused about different cmakelists project and build target)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(RePr_controller)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)

set(QT_VERSION 5)
set(REQUIRED_LIBS Core Gui Widgets)
set(REQUIRED_LIBS_QUALIFIED Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} main_window.cpp main_window.h main_window.ui resources/resources.qrc)
add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} FacadeLib)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} FacadeLib Utils)

find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION} COMPONENTS ${REQUIRED_LIBS} REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${REQUIRED_LIBS_QUALIFIED})
```

Messaging the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH directly from the cmakelists returns

```
D:/a/RePr/RePr/qt/Qt/5.12.11/mingw73_64/lib/cmake/
```

qt5 is here

```
D:/a/RePr/RePr/qt/Qt/5.12.11/mingw73_64/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake
```

finally, I got this message from configuring step

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="D:/a/RePr/RePr/qt/Qt/5.12.11/mingw73_64/lib/cmake/" -DQt5_DIR=D:/a/RePr/RePr/qt/Qt/5.12.11/mingw73_64/lib/cmake/Qt5/ -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" -B 'D:\a\RePr\RePr'/build
  shell: D:\a\_temp\msys\msys2.CMD {0}
  env:
    BUILD_TYPE: Release
    MSYSTEM: MINGW64
    pythonLocation: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.6\x64
    Qt5_Dir: D:/a/RePr/RePr/qt/Qt/5.12.11/mingw73_64
    QT_PLUGIN_PATH: D:/a/RePr/RePr/qt/Qt/5.12.11/mingw73_64/plugins
    QML2_IMPORT_PATH: D:/a/RePr/RePr/qt/Qt/5.12.11/mingw73_64/qml
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done

CMake Error at Controller/CMakeLists.txt:17 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindQt5.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5", but
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/a/RePr/RePr/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5" with any of
  the following names:

    Qt5Config.cmake
    qt5-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Qt5_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Qt5" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.


Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: related: [Building Qt Creator plugins with GitHub Actions](https://www.qt.io/blog/building-qt-creator-plugins-with-github-actions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH to Qt5_Dir:

```yaml
- name: Configure CMake
  env:
    CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: ${{env.Qt5_Dir}}
  run: cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${{env.BUILD_TYPE}} -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" -B '${{github.workspace}}'/build
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help. I doubt now it's possible. still the same error. variable is now visible
```
    CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: D:/a/RePr/RePr/qt/Qt/5.12.11/mingw73_64
```

Comment: @Ali-G178 It worked for me, see my test repo: https://github.com/eyllanesc/69108420

Comment: wow, I see. let me play around with it then.. thanks again :)

Comment: @eyllanesc ok, looking into the commit history everything became clear for me. the checkout action should be the first one as it clears (not sure, but seems to be) the workspace with qt already installed there. that's why the configuring step failed. thanks for your investigation!